# React Native change the value of key in object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native project. I am trying to setState for an object. I only need to change the value for the key isFolder. I am to javascript and not sure how to do this.

Below is a sample of what I am hoping to do. I would like to change the value for isFolder to false but at the same time keep the values of the other keys

what I have tried

```
  interface ItemType {
    parentUUID?: null | string;
    currentUUID?: null | string;
    isRootDirector?: true | false;
    headerTitle?: null | string;
    isFolder?: false | true;
  }

  const [item, setItem] = useState<ItemType>({});

  const Start = () => {
    // handle other stuff

    setItem(i => {...i, i.isFolder = false})
  }
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but your syntax is invalid. `setItem(i => ({ ...i, isFolder: false }))`

Answer (score 0):

As Zac commented,
Check your syntax. It should be `setItem(i => ({ ...i, isFolder: false }))`. A decent IDE would be able to highlight these syntax errors. If you are new to programming, I would recommend Visual Studio Code. Consider https://snack.expo.dev/ as an online option for React Native related stuff.